# Getting the value of a datagridview to a combobox. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

The thing im trying to do is to get the value from a datagridview table already populated, to an editing phase, textbox are filling nicely but I cant find a way to assign the value of the table to a combobox item.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {                                                      
        DataGridViewRow cliente = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
        textBoxDsClave.Text = cliente.Cells["dsClave"].Value.ToString();
        textBoxDsRazonSocial.Text = cliente.Cells["dsRazonSocial"].Value.ToString();
        comboBoxCnAceptaPromociones = cliente.Cells["cnAceptaPromociones"].Value.ToString(); //THIS ONE
    }
```

Extra info, the data type of "cnAceptaPromociones" is bool, so it just has either "true" or "false".

I'm really new to C#, and i'm having a hard time learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `SelectedValue` property:

```
comboBoxCnAceptaPromociones.SelectedValue =
    Convert.ToBoolean(cliente.Cells["cnAceptaPromociones"].Value);
```

Comment: Worked just as I needed, Thank you Grant.